# as3 evaluate string from json as object

Tags: actionscript-3, json, evaluation

I have a json object where I don't know some of the values at compile time, but I do know that all objects will be valid at runtime.  So in the example below, the first trace will output "50" and I want the second trace to output "100", the value of someObject.someparam, which gets defined at runtime. Is this possible? Thanks

```
var plan:Object = { "testParam": 50, "testParam2": "someObject.someParam" }
var someObject:Object = {"someParam": 100}// this actually doesn't get defined until runtime  

trace ("testParam " + plan.testParam);
trace ("testParam2 " + someSortOfInterpreter(plan.testParam2);
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make much sense to me as to why you are using a "JSON Object." JSON is text based notation that can later be interpreted by the specific coding language you are using.

So, assuming your JSON string is actually:

```
var jsonString:String = '{
    "testParam": 50,
    "testParam2": "someObject.someParam"
}';
```

You could just leave out the "testParam" property entirely, at compile time, then parse the string and set that property at runtime.

Start with:

```
var jsonString:String = '{
    "testParam": 50
}';
```

then:

```
var plan:Object = JSON.decode (jsonString);
plan.testParam2 = someObject.testParam;
```

This is assuming you're using the [as3coreLib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) JSON class to decode the json string.

Comment: hmm, we seem to have a disconnect.  I understand your first point about the string.  But the whole point here is that I MUST set testParam2 at compile time.  For example, at compile time, I might want to set param2 to a function name.  Then, when I read the json file, I would treat it like a function, like:  jsonString.testParam2(arguments);   But obviously I need some step in between.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are dynamic, it doesn't have to exist for you to create it at runtime.

```
var someObject:Object = { }; // Empty object with nothing defined in it

trace(someObject.someParam); // Traces out "undefined"
```

You can also check to see if it has been set

```
if (someObject.someParam != undefined)
```

You can set it whenever you want

```
someObject.someParam = 100;
```

and now, after it has been set, it will trace correctly

```
trace(someObject.someParam); // Traces out 100
```

Is this what you are having troubles with? If not, maybe you could give us more info about your problem.

Comment: changed and restated here, this may solve my problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461591/as3-function-pointer