# as3 function pointer

Tags: actionscript-3, function, pointers

```
private function myFunction(numIn:Number){
   trace ("numIn " + numIn);
}

var plan:Object = { "theFunctionName": "myFunction" }


// now use the function 

plan.theFunctionName(5);

// should trace out:  "numIn 5"
```

This won't work, but can you see what I'm trying to do?  It's kind of like a function pointer, or when you pass a function name into an event listener. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is:

```
var plan:Object = { theFunctionName: myFunction }
```

Answer (score 16):

Either do what Jacob suggested, or you can even just do:

```
// Your function.
function myFunction(numIn:Number):void
{
    trace("numIn " + numIn);
}


// Assign "myFunction" to the property "callback" of type "Function".
var callback:Function = myFunction;

// Call "myFunction" via "callback".
callback(5); // numIn 5
```