# ActionScript 3: Assigning a named function to a variable of type Function

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working with a game loop and am attempting to handle user input by assigning various methods to a variable of type Function depending on the games state.

I'm assigning a defined function called InputState1 to my Function variable inputFunction:

```
var inputFunction:Function = InputState1;
```

where InputState1 is:

```
public function InputState1():void
{
    // input logic
}
```

and call inputFunction in the game loop's update method:

```
override protected function update(timeDelta:Number):void
{
    trace(inputFunction);
    inputFunction();
}
```

When I trace the inputFunction, it returns an empty function.

Is it possible to assign a named function to a function variable and if so, how would I go about doing this properly?

**Solution:** I was invoking my function variables call method instead of just calling the function.  It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was invoking my function variable's call method instead of just calling the function. It works now and I've edited the code in my question to the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your argument is that you want a game state to be identified and act according to it, well you always can define a String holding the game state value which updates as game state changes, and make a function returning that string,(or directly comapre that string wth defined states)

```
var gameState:String="initial";

override protected function update(timeDelta:Number,gameState:String):void
{
  gameState="newstate"; //depending upon your condition requirement
}

if(gameState="requredState"){
    //do required stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm currently implementing the strategy you suggested, which works fine. I'm still interested in being able to assign defined functions to a variable of type function, if that is possible.

Thanks for the post!

Comment: I'm not able to vote up or down yet. Also, I'm looking for an answer on how to assign a function to a variable. I'll update my question to reflect that. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make a function pointer (a new term I just learned). I'll give this a try as soon as I can.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461591/as3-function-pointer